# Centroids of K-means clustering

Tags: k-means, unsupervised-learning

I was trying to cluster cities and came up with a problem:

I wanted the centroids to be obligatory in a city and they ended up in a desert area. I want to know if it is possible to "say" that the centroids have to be points in the input data. In order words, I want to find the n points in the input data that minimizes the sum of the distances of all points to this set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[K-medoids (or PAM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-medoids) is the algorithm you are looking for.